# kotlin lambda passed as argument to corda (v3.2) flow throws kryo serialization exception

Tags: corda

I have a Corda flow written in kotlin which takes lambda as an argument:

```
class ApproveFlow(val arg1: String, val arg2: (Amount<Currency>) -> Amount<Currency>) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>()
```

If I try to invoke the flow over RPC as shown below, Kryo throws an exception:

```
nodeBProxy.startFlow(::ApproveFlow, "abc", (BasicCalculator()::computeValue))
```

computeValue function is defined as below:

```
@CordaSerializable
interface Calculator {
    fun computeValue(purchasePrice: Amount<Currency>): Amount<Currency>
}

@CordaSerializable
class BasicCalculator  : Calculator {

    override fun computeValue(purchasePrice: Amount<Currency>): Amount<Currency> 
  { ...
    ...
    return 100.POUNDS

  }
}
```

Exception:

```
is not annotated or on the whitelist, so cannot be used in serialization corda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a function as a parameter to a flow is probably a bit ambitious. The node needs to evaluate it, after all, and checkpoint it so it can be evaluated later. If you really want to do this you can like so:

`val lambda = @CordaSerializable Runnable { whatever() }`

or

`val lambda = @CordaSerializable fun() { whatever() }`

.... *but* I'd suggest keeping it simple and just passing into plain old data objects. Yes, object serialization is powerful. But with great power comes great responsibility!

Comment: Thanks. If i am not wrong,  @CordaSerializable annotation is not applicable to target expressions or anonymous functions. ?

Comment: Ah, you might be right. But I realised it won't work for another reason too - the generated lambda object won't expose getters, which means in Corda 4 the engine will barf because it won't know how to read the object. I think for now we'll need to say this is unsupported.